# pylatex: How do I change the font size of my document?

Tags: python, latex, pylatex

I'm trying to change the basic font size of my document. This is my code:

```
from pylatex import Document, Command

if __name__ == '__main__':
    doc = Document('basic')
    doc.documentclass = Command(
        'documentclass',
        options=['48pt'],
        arguments=['book'],
    )
    doc.append('Some regular text.')
    doc.generate_pdf('full', clean=True)
```

But, the text isn't in 48-point text, and it stays the same whatever I change `options` to. How can I make it 48-point?

Comment: I've also tried adding `font_size='48pt'` as an argument to `Document(`. That doesn't help either.

Comment: Default latex classes only support predefined options for the size, e.g. 10pt, 11pt, 12pt, ... and not arbitrary values like 48pt. If you use `extbook` instead of `book`, a couple of more options are available, e.g. 20pt

Answer (score 0):

try

```
doc.preamble.append(pylatex.Package(name='extsizes'))
```